# Reference .NET DLL in Powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I currently need to unzip a file inside a powershell script, which was compressed using the Ionic.Zip.Lib which is part of the  [DotNetZip Project](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd). So I discovered, that is not possible to unzip it with the standard powershell way

```
Expand-Archive C:\a.zip -DestinationPath C:\a
```

So I decided to use a c# template inside powershell to do the work

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -ReferencedAssemblies @('System.IO', "D:\DotNetZip.dll", 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51') -Language CSharp 
$Source = @"
using Ionic.Zip;
using System.IO;
public class Unzipper
{
  public static void TryUnzipFile()
    {
        string zipfile = @"myPath\Test.zip";
        string dest = @"myPath\Test";
        string pw = "myPW";
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipfile))
        {
            zip.Password = pw;
            zip.ExtractAll(dest, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }
    }
}
"@
[Unzipper] | Get-Member -Static
```

So far so good:

```
   TypeName: Unzipper

Name            MemberType Definition                                                         
----            ---------- ----------                                                         
Equals          Method     static bool Equals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)         
new             Method     Unzipper new()                                                     
ReferenceEquals Method     static bool ReferenceEquals(System.Object objA, System.Object objB)
TryUnzipFile    Method     static void TryUnzipFile()
```

But when calling the function TryUnzipFile() I always get this exception

```
[Unzipper]::TryUnzipFile()

"An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry"

In D:\inlinecode.ps1:31 Zeichen:1
+ [Unzipper]::TryUnzipFile()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeInitializationException
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a translation of the error message for those who can't read German. A rough translation is usually sufficient.

Comment: the error sounds a bit like a 32/64 bit mismatch...and please add a check if the files exists at that path

Comment: Any way you could get to the wider exception details? Sounds like a constructor in the DLL might be failing at runtime

Comment: Ionic.Zip is not maintained any more and you should be using DotNetZip : https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/1.9.1.8#versions-body-tab

Comment: What happens when you reference `Ionic.Zip.dll` directly. For me your example works when I use `Ionic.Zip.dll` in Version=1.9.1.5 (it is compiled with AnyCPU no 32/64bit issue). But have to move Add-Type ... before `[Unzipper]::TryUnzipFile()`

Comment: @jdweng Yes I know, but still you have to use 'using Ionic.Zip' allthough I added the nuget package for DotNetZip. It seems like it is still used somewhere inside this dll.

Comment: @PinBack just tried it with the Ionic.Zip.dll, but same result for me :(

Comment: Did you try a clean build?  Error is due to an intermediate obj file that did not get recompiled after switching libraries.  The compile dependencies compare the date of the source file with the date if the obj.  If source didn't change the obj does not get recompiled.  So changing libraries so not change the date of the source.  Either use clean build or delete the bin folder to force everything to recompile.

Comment: Just tried a clean build: Now I get "The file or assembly "Ionic.Zip, Version=1.9.1.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=edbe51ad942a3f5c" or a dependency was not 
 was not found. The system cannot find the specified file."

Comment: Same with DotNetZip.dll
"The file or assembly "DotNetZip, Version=1.16.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6583c7c814667745" or a dependency of it 
 was not found. The system cannot find the specified file."